# Make a smoothly opening menu effect using Tailwind CSS and React JS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to transform the menu to have a smooth transition when it opens, but it's not working for me.

I've also tried using hidden class, but ran into the same problem.

Is there a way to make it open smoothly?

My attempt:

```
import React from "react";

export default function ModerSideMenu({}) {
  const [menu, setMenu] = React.useState({
    home: true,
  });

  return (
    <div className="w-64 bg-blue-900 h-full p-4 text-white">
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between  uppercase font-semibold w-full">
          <div className="ml-2 flex-row flex items-center space-x-2">
            <i className="fas fa-home" />
            <p className="">Home</p>
          </div>
          <i
            className={`transform transition-all ease-out duration-300 select-none fas ${
              menu.home ? "fa-angle-up" : "fa-angle-down"
            } mr-2`}
            onClick={() => setMenu({ ...menu, home: !menu.home })}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`ml-4 mt-2 space-y-1 text-sm transform transition-all ease-out duration-300 z-20 select-none ${
            !menu.home ? "-translate-y-full" : "translate-y-0"
          }`}
          hidden={!menu.home}
        >
          <p>- Home 1</p>
          <p>- Home 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="relative mt-2">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between  uppercase font-semibold w-full">
          <div className="ml-2 flex-row flex items-center space-x-2">
            <i className="fas fa-home" />
            <p className="">Home 2</p>
          </div>
          <i className="justify-self-end fas fa-angle-down mr-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-4 mt-2 space-y-1 text-sm">
          <p>- Home 3</p>
          <p>- Home 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add state conditions for the css like hover/focus.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property#applying-conditionally  
Try with hover and see if it works.

Comment: Alternatively, you can give the menu `h-0` and then replace that with the menu height to cause it to transition.